# Display openweathermap (API) data on website using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

when i want enter a city  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWRt.png), nothing happens, no error in my console, i don't know why

this is my code :

ajax.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitLocation').click(function(){

        //get value from input field
        var city = $("#city").val();
        $.post('PHP/controller.php', {variable: city});

        //check not empty
        if (city != ''){

            $.ajax({

                url: "PHP/router.php",
                // url :"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city +"&lang=fr"+"&units=metric" + "&APPID=697edce53ba912538458a39d776ca24e",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.weather[0].description);
                    console.log(data.main);
                    console.log(data.main.temp);

                    var information = show(data);
                    $("#show").html(information);
                }
            });

        }else{
            $('#error').html('Field cannot be empty');
        }

    });
})

function show(data){
    return "<h3>Témpérature: "+ data.main.temp +"°C"+"</h3>" + "<h3>"+ data.weather[0].description +"</h3>";
}
```

this is my router.php, my js call the router

```php
<?php
require('../PHP/controller.php');

if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
   return getWeatherCity($_GET['city']);

}
else {
    echo'Error';
}
?>
```

i know that i can do this only with js or only with php but i want use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any request happening in the "Requests" tab of your DevTool?

You should see a request towards `PHP/router.php` and the associated status code. Given that you might collect clues to debug what's going on.